# complex analysis cardiodid difficult question?

Tags: complex-analysis

In what zone is mapped the zone defined by the cardiodid $ρ = 2(1+\cosϕ)$ from the analytic branch of the function $w=\sqrt{z}$ which takes positive values in the positive half real axis.
answer in my book the answer is : the inside of the circle $u^2 + v^2=2u$

Now,when we have $z=x+ iy$ and and $w=u+iy$ we equal the real and imaginary parts and then Impose what we want to map..how about here?

Comment: Use $z = w^2$ here. $x = u^2 - v^2$ and $y = 2uv$.

Comment: No man,I mean thanks but I don't know how to relate  $ρ = 2 *(1+ cosϕ)$ to $z=w^2$

Comment: Ah, the curve is given by $2(1+\cos \phi)e^{i\phi} = 2(1+\cos \phi)\cos \phi + i\cdot 2(1+\cos\phi)\sin\phi$. That is $z$, so $u^2 - v^2 = 2(1+\cos\phi)\cos\phi$ and $2uv = 2(1+\cos\phi)\sin\phi$. Now play with some trigonometric identities to get a nicer form.

Comment: Even though I dont get the same answer as in my book..I really have no idea how to do this,this is an old exercise that my teacher didnt solve..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the parametrization $z(\varphi) = 2(1+\cos\varphi)e^{i\varphi}$ of the cardioid. With the ansatz $z = x+iy = w^2 = (u+iv)^2 = u^2-v^2 + i2uv$, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
u^2 - v^2 &= 2(1+\cos \varphi)\cos\varphi & 2uv &= 2(1+\cos\varphi)\sin\varphi\\
\leadsto u^2-v^2 &= 4\cos^2 \frac{\varphi}{2}\left(\cos^2 \frac{\varphi}{2} - \sin^2 \frac{\varphi}{2}\right) & 2uv &= 4\cos^2 \frac{\varphi}{2}\left(2\sin\frac{\varphi}{2}\cos\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)
\end{align}$$

with the obvious solution (unique up to signs, but the other sign would be the wrong branch of the square root)

$$\begin{align}u &= 2\cos^2 \frac{\varphi}{2} & v &= 2\sin\frac{\varphi}{2}\cos\frac{\varphi}{2}\\
\leadsto u &= 1 + \cos\varphi & v &= \sin \varphi.
\end{align}$$

And that is

$$u^2 + v^2 = (1+\cos\varphi)^2 + \sin^2\varphi = 1 + 2\cos\varphi + \cos^2\varphi + \sin^2\varphi = 2(1+\cos\varphi) = 2u.$$

Comment: This is great.Probably one of the best/most detailed answer I have encountered here until now.

Comment: Really,why does it say only "Inside of the circle" in my book?

Comment: What I have computed here is the boundary curve. The mapping maps the inner region of the cardioid to the interior of the circle. For analysis, one is concerned with the open sets bounded by the respective curves, and isn't very interested in the curves themselves. But of course, to find out which region is mapped to which, inspecting the behaviour on the boundary is often helpful.